# Screen sharing and camera stream with Twilio SDK

Tags: ios, twilio, replaykit, twilio-video

I'm trying to implement an app a'la google hangout where you can create a video conference *and* share your screen when needed using Twilio SDK.

Screen recording should go system-wide so I'm using Replay Kit 2 and the Broadcast Upload Extension.

The problem is how can I upload screen data from the extension to the same Twilio room started in the app?

I'm looking at Twilio example code: https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift/tree/master/ReplayKitExample
What they do is connect to the room from within the extension.
My flow is different though - I initiate the call from the main app and then I can initiate screen sharing.

I imagine Twilio SDK could generate presigned URL which is shared with the extension and then it uploads data stream there.
And idea if this is achieveable with Twilio?